# Docker exec via rancher API

Tags: docker, rancher

I'm hoping that its possible to do this something like this via Rancher's REST API. Does anybody know if its possible?

```
cat data.txt | docker exec -i my_container sh -c 'cat >/data.txt'
```

Seems I can interact with docker exec using this:

```
curl -X "POST" "http://123.123.123.123:8080/v2-beta/containers/1i177?action=execute" \
     -H "Cookie: PL=rancher" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -u user:password \
     -d $'{
    "attachStdin": true,
   "attachStdout": true,
    "command": [
        "ls"
], 
"tty": true
}'
```

Which returns this:

```
url":"ws:\/\/123.123.123.123:8080\/v1\/exec\/"
```

So I assume I need to connect to this using a WebSocket?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the `token` that was also included in that response either as a header (`Authorization: Bearer <token>`) or query param (`?token=<token>`).

You also probably want `tty: false`, since it is unlikely you are a TTY :-)

Comment: Thanks for this. I have it working but whilst I can do an 'ls' and get the results back if I try to use 'touch' it returns an error.

Comment: rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"/bin/bash -c touch /carl\\\": stat /bin/bash -c touch /carl: no such file or directory\"\n"